# How to convert a dataframe to year-and-month separated time series table in R

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to convert a dataframe containing 3000+ observations collected every day into a time series table. But I get only a few first observations. I would like to get an average for each month in each year.

For example, on August, 2020, the average should be 750. Like this.

I would like to know if there is any way to get averages by month in each year?
Could you please suggest me?

The data frame is like this
[image]

But I want this time series table containing averages by month in each year

[image]

**Sample data is here:**

```
structure(list(Date = c("2015-08-07", "2015-08-08", "2015-08-09", 
"2015-08-10", "2015-08-11", "2015-08-12", "2015-08-13", "2015-08-14", 
"2015-08-15", "2015-08-16", "2015-08-17", "2015-08-18", "2015-08-19", 
"2015-08-20", "2015-08-21", "2015-08-22", "2015-08-23", "2015-08-24", 
"2015-08-25", "2015-08-26"), Open = c("2.831620", "2.793760", 
"0.706136", "0.713989", "0.708087", "1.058750", "1.222240", "1.810920", 
"1.802890", "1.684350", "1.581190", "1.215300", "1.166930", "1.251180", 
"1.477520", "1.396290", "1.375000", "1.345590", "1.228610", "1.132790"
), High = c("3.536610", "2.798810", "0.879810", "0.729854", "1.131410", 
"1.289940", "1.965070", "2.261880", "1.877240", "1.695240", "1.581190", 
"1.331160", "1.317990", "1.533300", "1.556420", "1.476410", "1.409700", 
"1.362780", "1.241820", "1.202480"), Low = c("2.521120", "0.714725", 
"0.629191", "0.636546", "0.663235", "0.883608", "1.171990", "1.754750", 
"1.570980", "1.089810", "1.185340", "1.087050", "1.166930", "1.248330", 
"1.352800", "1.352680", "1.297770", "1.231270", "1.128650", "1.061830"
), Close = c("2.772120", "0.753325", "0.701897", "0.708448", 
"1.067860", "1.217440", "1.827670", "1.827870", "1.688900", "1.566030", 
"1.203610", "1.087050", "1.258860", "1.464920", "1.395290", "1.379230", 
"1.352590", "1.231270", "1.140190", "1.159980"), Adj.Close = 
c("2.772120", "0.753325", "0.701897", "0.708448", "1.067860", "1.217440", "1.827670", 
"1.827870", "1.688900", "1.566030", "1.203610", "1.087050", "1.258860", 
"1.464920", "1.395290", "1.379230", "1.352590", "1.231270", "1.140190", 
"1.159980"), Volume = c("164329", "674188", "532170", "405283", 
"1463100", "2150620", "4068680", "4637030", "2554360", "3550790", 
"1942830", "1485680", "1486240", "2843760", "2020970", "948310", 
"1589300", "924920", "1307180", "1056750")), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

all
I also come up with my own solution. I aggregate the data with mean by year and month like this

```
ts_data$Month <- months(ts_data$Date)

#  Get years
ts_data$Year <- format(ts_data$Date, format = "%Y")

#  Aggregate Close on months and year and get mean
ts_data <- aggregate(. ~ Month + Year, ts_data, mean)
```

And I create a time series using this method

```
ts_df <- ts(ts_data[, "Close"], frequency = 12, start = c(2015, 8), end = c(2021, 10))
```

And this is the result.
[image]